# DisplayTag library question - Problem with Html Tags

Tags: struts2, displaytag

```
<display:column  title="Email" autolink="true">
            skushwaha@sitmobile.com<br>
            satworld98@gmail.com<br>
</display:column>
```

I am getting the o/p as

```
<a href="mailto:skushwaha@sitmobile.com<br>">skushwaha@sitmobile.com<br></a>
<a href="mailto:satworld98@gmail.com<br>">satworld98@gmail.com<br>
```

while exporting it as PDF ot excel.

Any work around??

Answer (score 1):

I have tried without 
 tags instead, and that's works for me. ( http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/1355/screenshotwpn.png )